# Is there a way to the use the quick look utility on mac with Java?

Tags: java, macos

I am just curious, if this can be done. If I can "trigger' quick look some how from java with a specific file, like a .jpg file.

Comment: Voting to close: completely unclear what you are asking, edit your question otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an Applescript from java using this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("do shell script \"qlmanage -p \" & \"somepath/somefile\"").append("\n")

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
try {
    engine.eval(sb.toString());
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank You!!! It worked but it seems that this is isn't the "native" quick look one gets when one presses the space bar on a file, it seems like this is some sort of "debugging version" apple keeps on macs, because at the top of the quick look window it says "[DEBUG ]". Regardless, Thank you!!!!!